# How to optimize my R code to eliminate NEIGHBORING duplicates row-wise in a dataframe using vectorization instead of looping

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe

Edited question:

My dataframe looks like this.

```
x1 <- c("a", "c", "f", "j")
x2 <- c("b", "c", "g", "k")
x3 <- c("b", "d", "h", NA)
x4 <- c("a", "e", "i", NA)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, stringsAsFactors=F)

df

  x1 x2   x3   x4
1  a  b    b    a
2  c  c    d    e
3  f  g    h    i
4  j  k <NA> <NA>
```

I wrote a loop to eliminate NEIGHBORING duplicate values in each row.

```
for ( i in 1:4 ) {

   for ( j in 1:3 ) {

     if ( df[i, 4-j+1] == df[i, 4-j] & is.na(df[i, 4-j+1]) == F ) {

       df[i, 4-j+1] <- NA

     } else { 

       df[i, 4-j+1] <- df[i, 4-j+1]
     }
   }
}
```

The result looks like this.

```
  x1   x2   x3   x4
1  a    b <NA>    a
2  c <NA>    d    e
3  f    g    h    i
4  j    k <NA> <NA>
```

However, the original dataframe is quite big so the loop doesn't seem to be an appropriate approach.

Could you please show me how to optimize?

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for not asking more precisely.

Rami

Comment: When you are facing a problem that needs to be solved row wise, the solution will usually be a non-vectorized one (as you can see in both provided answers) simply because R is designed to work with vectors, not with rows. If you really despaired for a vectorized solution, Check the `Rcpp` package which allows you writing vectrorized functions using C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove duplicates wherever there are on the row

```
df[t(apply(df,1,duplicated))]<-NA
```

To remove only neighbouring duplicates, this should work :

```
df[]<-t(apply(df,1,function(rg){
            if(any(duplicated(rg))) {
                inddupl<-c(F,rg[2:length(rg)]==rg[1:(length(rg)-1)])
                rg[inddupl]<-NA
            }
            return(rg)
                   }))
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is not precise. What I want to do is elmininate only neighboring duplicated entries. I need to edit my question.

Comment: @RamiAl-Fahham, I edited my answer, I hope it now fulfills your criteria.